# Predicting probability distribution with partial information about the distribution

Tags: machine-learning

I need to predict predict probability distribution for a given input data. However instead of having labeled data, I have partial information about the output probability distribution. For example, if the distribution is over four classes, I know correct value of probability for one of the classes for a given input. Following are sample set of data

y_1 -> (?, 0.25, ?, ?)

y_2 -> (?, ?, 0.1, ?)

i.e., for y_1, we know that probability of belonging it to class 2 is 25%. However we do not know anything about the other three classes. Is there a way I can perform machine learning on this kind of data. One hueristic approach is to distribute the remaining probability eaqually. I was wondering if there is any work which deals with above kind of problem. Any pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an example of logged contextual bandit where you use logged data derived from an exploration experiment where you know the probability of chosen action.More details and example : https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Logged-Contextual-Bandit-Example